# Rgd: Subnetting about 370 hosts on a /24 Network

Tags: networking, subnet

Rgd: Subnetting about 370 hosts on a /24 Network

I am doing subnetting for the following.

There is a school, which got level 1 which is main lobby and 5 levels of classrooms ( level 2 to 6 )

I calculated that level 1 will use 161 hosts.
Level 2-6 - each will use 55 hosts per level

**So i was wondering how do i subnet it .**

For the main IP address is 203.218.71.0/24

I was thinking to subnet 3/4 to Main Lobby - I can split the main lobby into 3 sections with about 60 hosts each section

I was thinking to subnet 1/4 to level 2-6 floor

Which then further subnet them by slicing into 2 slice ( 4 levels per slice ) 
Each slice will have about 60 hosts ( can settle 4 levels )

Total we will use 5 out of 8 slices ( 1/2 x 1/4 ) - 5 levels

But for the ip address, how do i do it, is my subnetting workable ?

My main purpose is to link the whole school and cover the internal network, which the one connect to the internet is the main router > which then distribute to the switch & access point and do the linking.

Thanks

Hope to see your comment & thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put 370 hosts in a single /24 - there's only room for 254 hosts in a /24.

In any event, subnetting should be split by *function* and not by physical location.

Rather than looking at levels, look at what groups of systems actually need to be in the same broadcast domain.  Use VLANs to allow machines to exchange traffic directly on the same subnet, even if they're on different floors.

Keep student accessible machines separate from school administration, and put a firewall between them.

Look at using NAT where appropriate (class room machines?).

Comment: But how do i implement NAT in my case, considering i have a main router,2 switch,2 accesspoint at lobby, and 1 router, 1 switch , 1 AccessPoint at each floor ( level 2 -6 )

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but you should have thought of that before now...  Designing and provisioning a network for 370 hosts is _not_ a small undertaking, and should be done by a networking professional.

Comment: you could divide the different floors/lobby's by different subnets, just make sure the router knows all of them so if the different vlans want to communicate they will have to go via the router. (through 1 interface per vlan or trunking)

Comment: @Bulki it's pretty unlikely that he has the right equipment to do this, and he doesn't have enough IP addresses.

Comment: @Alnitak Indeed possible, but is the better way to implement this. If he needs a bigger subnet, use a /23 instead of a /24. If you don't have much broadcast traffic, this could still have a good performance.

Comment: @Bulki please go back and read what I've written.  Splitting by physical location is generally not appropriate, he should split by _function_.   I'm also concerned about seeing he has a single "AccessPoint" per floor.  If by that he means Wi-Fi, he's in for a further world of pain.

Comment: @Alnitak splitting by function is indeed the way to go, if you can implement different vlans on for example one floor and do the routing between them if wanted. If this is not possible, I would suggest splitting by location doh. This is a logical vs physical debate. It is very dependable on what his equipment is capable of.

but for argument sake: function splitting is indeed the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific need for every host to have a public IP address (which you can't do anyway, see Alnitak's response above), I would stay away from it, for a number of reasons.  You don't need a /24, a /30 would likely suit your needs just fine, using .1 as your provider gateway and .2 as your main WAN IP.

Use NAT for your segments, and use a logical RFC1918 scheme.  For example, use 192.168.1.0/24 for the first floor, 192.168.2.0/24 for the second floor, etc..  Factor in eventual growth, so maybe bump each segment up to a /22.  Private IP space is free and plentiful.  Use 10.0.0.0/8 and give out a /16 to each floor if you want, whatever works for your eventual needs.

Overall, good design trumps all.  The alternative is a lot of wasted time and energy to re-number everything after the fact.  If you need additional public IPs for a specific reason, change to suit your needs, but public IPs for classroom use is a big waste of precious IPv4 resources that can easily be served by NAT.

Also, when listing your equipment, it would be helpful to note the actual devices you are using, so appropriate procedures can be pointed out.  As a start with NAT, here is the main Cisco doc for it (again, I have no idea what equipment you are using, so take this link with a grain of salt if you're not using Cisco gear):

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk361/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094e77.shtml